# How do I make a multiple Selection in a Rails From for one part of the form/table/model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, multipleselection

I have a nested table called products nested under the parties table and one of the comluns is "brand". A product has a quantity, color and "brand". For "brand" I want the user to be able to do a multiple selection and collection on as many brands as the users want per product. How would I do this? I installed the "rails chosen gem", but it seems I need allot more than that.

Is it even possible for one column in a table to have multiple collection per user and product? Also it seems I should use indexing?

Code:

```
Product.rb:
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :party_id, :party, :id, :brand, :color, :name, :quantity
belongs_to :party
BRAND_TYPES = ["Hugs", "Kisses", "Love" ]
end

Party.rb:
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :user_id, presence: true
attr_accessible :name, :products_attributes, :products, :user_id
belongs_to :user
has_many :products
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, allow_destroy: true
end

_product_fields.html.erb:
<table>

<tr> 
<td> <%= f.label :name, "Product Name" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.text_field :name %> </td>
<td> <%= f.label :color, "Color" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.text_field :color %> </td>
<td> <%= f.label :Quantity, "Quantity" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.text_field :quantity %> </td>
<td> <%= f.label :brand, "Brand" %> </td>
<td> <%= f.select :brand, Product::BRAND_TYPES, :multiple => true %> </td>
<td> <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %></td>



</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: Would you add your product.rb code (specifically the section where you relate to the Brand table)

Comment: Cool, I added a bunch of stuff.